# How do I, within python, retrieve a sparse matrix stored by julia in a .jld file?

Tags: python, python-2.7, julia, hdf5

Using julia, I can save a sparse matrix in a .jld file (which is using the HDF5 format) like so:

```
a=spzeros(3,3);
a[1,1]=2.0
a[2,1]=1.0
a[3,1]=5
@save("sparsematrix.jld",a)
```

Now I want to retrieve this matrix in python (using h5py), so I tried the following:

```
import h5py 
filename="sparsematrix.jld"
f = h5py.File(filename, 'r')
data= f["a"][()]
f.close()
```

Printing `data` will return `(3, 3, <HDF5 object reference>, <HDF5 object reference>, <HDF5 object reference>)`, so I tried accessing the object references with: `f[data[2]]`, which returns `<HDF5 dataset "00000001": shape (4,), type "<i8">` but now I'm stuck.

So how do I get the sparse matrix out of the .jld file?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, found it myself, after wrapping my head around the CSC format:

```
import h5py 
from scipy.sparse import csc_matrix

filename="sparsematrix.jld"
f = h5py.File(filename, 'r')
data= f["a"][()]

column_ptr=f[data[2]][:]-1 ## correct indexing from julia (starts at 1)
indices=f[data[3]][:]-1 ## correct indexing
values =f[data[4]][:]
csc_matrix((values,indices,column_ptr), shape=(data[0],data[1])).toarray()

f.close()
```

Comment: Looks like julia is following matlab practice.  Scipy has more sparse formats.